# Get Date from String '2011-08-16T19:03:21.000Z'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter, date-format

I ask a database for the date of an object.  I get back a string as such: `2011-08-16T19:03:21.000Z` (Here's another one: `2011-08-12T02:13:16.000Z`);

Edit:  Here is another one that I made August 16th, 2011, at 12:51 PM for testing purposes: `2011-08-16T19:51:24.000Z`

I want to convert this date to another format for display purposes.  This format may change in the future, so I don't want to do direct string manipulation.  The best thing to do is turn it into an NSDate, and then back to the correctly formatted string.  However, I cannot, for the life of me, get the darn string into an NSDate.

```
- (NSString *)makeDateStringReadable:(NSString *)dateString {
    NSLog(@"The String: %@", dateString);
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzzz"];
    NSDate *theDate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"The Date: %@", theDate);
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *finalString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    [formatter release];
    return finalString;
}
```

The original string is passed in, and is logged out, but the "The Date:" log always shows null.  I'm assuming the format is not correct... but I can't get it to be correct.  I've tried using [this](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) as a reference as well.

Can I get the aid of a DateFormatter guru?  Thank you so much!

Comment: You can find a working implementation here: http://devbytom.blogspot.fr/2011/04/rfc-3339-dates-and-ios-parsing.html

Comment: Working Format: '[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];' 

Copied from below comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One problem (but possibly not *the* problem) is that that `zzzz` is not the right specification for `000Z`. The end of the [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) timestamp is not a four-character timezone specification, but fractional seconds plus a literal "Z". So try changing `zzzz` to `SSS'Z'`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I tried "[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];", but it's still null.

Comment: After playing around with it some more (and having a friend help), I got it working with: '[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];'  Thank you!

Comment: NSDateFormatter is one of the slowest things-that-shoud-not-be-slow i have encountered on iOS (and Mac). They are really expensive to make. Keep that in mind if you are making 10,000 of them. You can make one, then keep it for the entire program execution. (A singleton).

Comment: I am dealing with a web application that only accepts date fields in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss`, but sends me the dates back int eh format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`!!! I had to setup a dedicated formatter for each direction!